# Why do we need to mention inheritAll="false"?

Tags: java, ant

Can someone please explain to me what the use is of `inheritall` and what happens if I put `inheritAll="false"`? Also, what is the difference between ant and antcall in antscript?

Answer (score 1):

See  [Parameters in Ant site](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html) Here is the extract
**inheritAll    If true, pass all properties to the new Ant project. Defaults to true.**

To answer your secodn query see another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756816/whats-the-difference-between-antcall-and-ant-tasks) .

Thanks,
Keshava.

Comment: thanks,but i want to know if inheritAll="false" what happens –  user3427658 just now   edit

Comment: Again quoting from the ant site 

**By default, all of the properties of the current project will be available in the new project. Alternatively, you can set the inheritAll attribute to false and only "user" properties (i.e., those passed on the command-line) will be passed to the new project.**

So if you set inheritAll=false, only command line properties are passed to the new project.